# OOP Date Conversion - Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to OOP and need some help. (JAVA) Instructions: Write a complete class called Date. An object of this class represents a date, i.e., a day of the month (an integer between 1 and 31), a month( an integer between 1 and 12) and a year (an integer). Add to this class the following methods:

- A default constructor- creates a date object initialized to the given date
- A constructor with three parameters: day, moth, year - creates a date object initialized to the given date.
- printeDate - This method writes the date to the screen in the format month day, year, where the month is the name of the month
  -checkDate - This method returns true if and only if the current date value constitutes a valid date. (Month is between 1 and 12, day is between 1 and number of days in given month (leap year conditions apply), and year is greater than or equal to 1900.

I have done some preliminary work on the class but cannot test it for some reason. Here is the class Date without the method checkDate and an incomplete printDate method.

After that is the test file that will NOT run.

```
    public class Date 
    {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String monthString;
    public Date()
    {
        day = 1;
        month = 1;
        year = 2000;
        monthString = "defualt";
    }
    public Date(int userDay, int userMonth, int userYear)
    {
        day = userDay;
        month = userMonth;
        year = userYear;
    }
    public String printDate()
    {
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1: monthString  = "January";
                    break;
            case 2: monthString  = "February";
                    break;
            case 3: monthString  = "March";
                    break;
            case 4: monthString  = "April";
                    break;
            case 5: monthString  = "May";
                    break;
            case 6: monthString  = "June";
                    break;
            case 7: monthString  = "July";
                    break;
            case 8: monthString  = "August";
                    break;
            case 9: monthString  = "Septemeber";
                    break;
            case 10: monthString  = "Octoboer";
                    break;
            case 11: monthString  = "Novemeber";
                    break;
            case 12: monthString  = "December";
                    break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid Input";
                    break;
        }
        return monthString;
    }
}
```

And the class test file:

```
public class Date_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date myDate = new Date(1,1,2015);
        System.out.println(myDate.printDate());
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html Highly recommended to read this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an `Object` of your custom class to test it.

**Tip** : [`Date`](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwigpdy2kKLJAhUDXRQKHYseBYwQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F6%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FDate.html&usg=AFQjCNHozmZNNi_25YWnXrUavfrjyxIt1A) is the name of a class that already exists in Java, try maybe something like `CustomDate` or `MyDateClass`

---

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date myDate = new Date(1,1,2015); // 1st Jan 2015
    System.out.println(myDate.printDate());
}
```

---

### EDIT

Another problem is the returned `String` from your `printDate()` method.
This is an idea of correction, since you're only returning the month.

```
return monthString + day + "," + year;
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that. Are the constructors set up correctly per the instructions? I was a little unsure about that.

Comment: @frillybob Yes, the constructor seems ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am in late. Yes it's your problem. You should call your constructor and after call printDate.

I have done some of the code:

```
package oop.date.conversion;

public class Date {
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

private transient String monthString = "";
private transient boolean isDateOkay;

public Date()
{
    day = 1;
    month = 1;
    year = 2000;
    monthString = "January";
    isDateOkay = true;
}

public Date(int userDay, int userMonth, int userYear)
{
    day = userDay;
    month = userMonth;
    year = userYear;

    isDateOkay = checkDate();

    if( isDateOkay )
        checkAndUpdateMonth(true);
}

public void printDate()
{
    if( checkDate() == true )
        System.out.println( this.toString() );
    else
        System.out.println("Erreur on date");
}

public boolean checkDate()
{
    if( checkAndUpdateMonth(false) != true )
        return false;
    if( checkDay() != true )
        return false;
    if( checkYear() != true )
        return false;
    return true;
}

private boolean checkAndUpdateMonth(boolean update)
{
    if( month < 1 || month > 12 )
        return false;

    switch (month) {
    case 1: monthString  = "January";
    break;
    case 2: monthString  = "February";
    break;
    case 3: monthString  = "March";
    break;
    case 4: monthString  = "April";
    break;
    case 5: monthString  = "May";
    break;
    case 6: monthString  = "June";
    break;
    case 7: monthString  = "July";
    break;
    case 8: monthString  = "August";
    break;
    case 9: monthString  = "Septemeber";
    break;
    case 10: monthString  = "Octoboer";
    break;
    case 11: monthString  = "Novemeber";
    break;
    case 12: monthString  = "December";
    break;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean checkDay()
{
    if( day < 1 )
        return false;
    // TODO
    return true;
}

private boolean checkYear()
{
    if( year < 1900 )
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return day + " " + monthString + " " + year;
}
}
```

And the main test:

```
package oop.date.conversion;

public class TestDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date1 = new Date(5, 12, 1954);
    date1.printDate();

    Date date2 = new Date(0, 12, 1954);
    date2.printDate();

    Date date3 = new Date(5, 13, 1954);
    date3.printDate();

    Date date4 = new Date(5, 12, 1854);
    date4.printDate();
}

}
```